# PHP encryption empty string

Tags: php, security, encryption, aes

I have this code

```
define('CRYPTKEY','rx4/YK51nJo7LuRnZAz/jpXZbCunkNplneL6ugkBs5g=');
define('CRYPTALGO','aes-256-cbc');

public function crypt($text){
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
$encryption_key = base64_decode(CRYPTKEY);
$cryptedid = openssl_encrypt ($newid,CRYPTALGO,$encryption_key,0,$iv);
return base64_encode($cryptedid.'::'.$iv);
}

public function decrypt($text){
    $encryption_key = base64_decode(CRYPTKEY);
    list($encrypted_data, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($text), 2);
    return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data,CRYPTALGO,$encryption_key,0,$iv);
  }
```

CRYPTKEY was created like this :

```
base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
```

But I keep having a empty string as decoded text ....

Somebody can help me to figure out why ?

Comment: Why don't you just write the id out as plaintext?! What's the purpose of this insecure encryption?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I pass the id encrypted to obfuscate the id of the row in the database where I'm adding sensitive data. 
If you have no access to the server, please share with me how "insecure" is this script by sending me the script to crack this algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `$text` anywhere in your `crypt()` function. Thus you encrypt an empty ('non-existing') string.

You'll have to change `$newid` (in `crypt()`) to `$text` to make it work. Like this:

```
$cryptedid = openssl_encrypt($text,CRYPTALGO,$encryption_key,0,$iv);
//                           ^^^^^
```

Comment: I've spent like a day on this and it was so simple. Thank you so much

Comment: The good thing is that I spent the other half of the day finding a good algorithm in PHP, so maybe someone will find this post useful someday

Comment: At the risk of sounding rude, if something so simple was breaking your code, you might want to not design your own cryptography. [Read here why developers are often told not to design their own cryptography](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it). Check out [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) for a secure drop-in library to use instead.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski I'm not designing anything, i just want to obfuscate a string for a simple get request. I won't install a full library to do that. I appreciate your concern though.

Comment: [Be very careful here](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php).